# How to install xsl extension for PHP in windows version of MAMP?

Tags: php, xml, xslt, mamp, mamp-pro

I'm trying to use MAMP pro 5 to setup a PHP dev environment. But my sites are not running properly. I keep getting 500 errors.

I found out I need the XSL extension for PHP. I tried php version 7.3.19 and 7.4.2. I did a lot of research online. The solution I found is to uncomment `;extension=php_xsl.dll` in php.ini. But I don't have this line in php.ini.

I tried manually adding a php_xsl.dll file to ext folder and add `extension=php_xsl.dll` in php.ini file but the extension is not showing up in phpinfo(). I checked the log file and found the error

"Unable to load dynamic library 'php_xsl.dll' (tried: C:\MAMP\bin\php\php7.3.25\ext\php_xsl.dll (The specified procedure could not be found.),"

How can I install the xsl extension?

Comment: I'm with the same problem. Looks like Linux has solutions for that but Windows doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I originally got the file from IIS version of PHP. I guess it's a non thread version of php which is different from the one MAMP use. I ended up downloading a thread safe version of php and grabbed the dll file in there. The problem is finally solved.

Comment: Ive tried this but i'm getting php_xsl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 0):

You have to download a newer version of PHP through MAMP software.
Go to `Languages` > `PHP` and click on `+` and select `7.4.30`.
After the download you can see that the folder `MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.30/ext/` will have the `php_xsl.dll` extension. By default it's enabled, so no need to touch `php.ini` file.