# php_yaml extension is installed but can't be found

Tags: php, dll, pecl

I want to contribute in a laravel project.
I get an error about yaml_parse so I probably haven't installed the php_yaml application.
On the pecl download page, there is a zip for the most recent version and a .dll file for the version below. I download the .dll file, add the extension to my php.ini but I get an error the plugin can't be found

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_yaml.dll' (tried: ext\php_yaml.dll (Kan opgegeven module niet vinden), ext\php_php_yaml.dll.dll (Kan opgegeven module niet vinden)) in Unknown on line 0

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'yaml' (tried: ext\yaml (Kan opgegeven module niet vinden), ext\php_yaml.dll (Kan opgegeven module niet vinden)) in Unknown on line 0

I can assure you this .dll file is actually in the correct folder, here is the prove
[image: yaml.dll inside the ext folder]

Here is my php.ini
I'm not sure how I should name the extension so I did it with both names..

```
;extension=tidy
;extension=xsl
extension=php_yaml.dll
extension=yaml
extension=zip

;zend_extension=opcache
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/264586/locating-php-extension-folder-using-bash

Comment: @Alex, this looks like a fix for Ubuntu. But I'm working on a windows environment

Comment: I know, it was more about a hint to be absolutely sure you know in which dir the extensions need to be. I dont know about windows, but maybe the ext must be compiled for your php version exactly. Are you using xampp?

Comment: I'm using MAMP.. :p
Looks a bit like Xampp but it should be doing the trick because I've never encountered this issue in the past

Comment: So which php version are you running and what is the full path to the ext dir?

Comment: This seems to be a common problem in windows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72830768/how-to-install-xsl-extension-for-php-in-windows-version-of-mamp

Comment: @Alex, so my MAMP is running on php 8.1 but the php on my computer is php 8.2 
However, I added the extension to my mamp folder but it still listens to the php versions that is installed with windows

Comment: The website that youre trying to run, does it run with MAMP? Then the OS php doesnt matter. Again, do a phpinfo in your project and find out the ext directory. If you put the ext in there and enable it via php.ini, it should run. If you did all that and it still doesnt, it might be a mamp/ windows problem.

Comment: "I added the extension to my mamp folder but it still listens to the php versions that is installed with windows" - how do you figure?

Comment: Because when I commented the extensions in the php.ini in the mamp directive, the error didn't change. I did the same thing on windows php ini and than the error wasn't mentioned..

Comment: Do you run the website/ project from within the mamp htdocs? Im asking you a last time to run phpinfo();, it tells you all you need

Comment: No I don't
in my powershell terminal, I use the php -m command to see all extensions and I get the errors

Comment: Your CLI php has nothing to do with mamp unless youve explicitly linked it

Comment: Got it working. After intensive search I stumbled upon a github post that redirect me to this url. https://phpext.phptools.online/extension/file-formats/yaml-330
Here were the updated source files for php8.2 and above